# Advice installing PSPP on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

PSPP is an open source alternative to SPSS. Because of licensing issues it isn't in official Ubuntu repositories.  I have found downloads available for Ubuntu 20.10 and 18.04 at https://pkgs.org/download/pspp but I run 20.04 and don't want to upgrade.  Am I out of luck or is there a safe choice for me?  (I can follow directions but am not really adept at Linux yet - just switched over.)  Thx.

Comment: PSPP is available in the official Ubuntu repositories ([universe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638)) for all supported releases of Ubuntu EXCEPT 20.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install PSPP by using its package and dependencies from 20.10.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/libgsl25_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spread-sheet-widget/libspread-sheet-widget_0.6-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pspp/pspp_1.4.0-3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libgsl25_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ./libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ./libspread-sheet-widget_0.6-3_amd64.deb ./pspp_1.4.0-3_amd64.deb
```

And then launch it from menu or with `psppire` command.

Comment: Thx NOrbert.  Works like a charm.

Comment: Great! So you can accept my answer :)

Comment: Yes. I'm a newbie.  Is there a box to check?

Comment: The checkmark is in the left side of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Only a couple of months ago the answer from N0rbert worked for me like a charm on my Linux Mint 20.2 system. However, `libgsl25_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb` and `libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb` are no longer in the Universe archive.
Fortunately, I found these packages over at the Debian archive and amended N0rbert's response as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gsl/libgsl25_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gsl/libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spread-sheet-widget/libspread-sheet-widget_0.6-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pspp/pspp_1.4.0-3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libgsl25_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ./libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ./libspread-sheet-widget_0.6-3_amd64.deb ./pspp_1.4.0-3_amd64.deb
```

Worked a treat for me.